# Различие стандартных алгоритмов std::inclusive_scan и std::partial_sum

Tags: c++

> `std::exclusive_scan` - подобна std::partial_sum, не включает i-й
> элемент в i-ю "сумму"

С этим все ясно, но вот:

> `std::inclusive_scan`  - (C++17) подобна std::partial_sum, включает
> i-й элемент в i-ю "сумму"

Не очень понятно. И простая программа:

```
int arr[10] = { 2, 4, 6, 7, 3, 5, 1, 8, 9, 10 },
    arr1[10];
std::exclusive_scan(arr, arr + 10, arr1, 0);
//функция выводит все элементы последовательности
show(arr1); //0 2 6 12 19 22 27 28 36 45 

std::partial_sum(arr, arr + 10, arr1); 
show(arr1); //2 6 12 19 22 27 28 36 45 55

std::inclusive_scan(arr, arr + 10, arr1);
show(arr1); //2 6 12 19 22 27 28 36 45 55
```

показывает, что `std::inclusive_scan` выдает результат тот же, что и std::partial_sum

1. И с чем связана необходимость существования этого алгоритма?
2. Когда может быть удобнее применение `std::inclusive_scan`  вместо
   `std::partial_sum`?

(можно  просто привести пример кода)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первая разница небольшая - partial_sum не имеет начального значения. inclusive_scan  - имеет.

Вторая разница - это в особенностях "бинарной операции", которая может быть передана отдельным параметром. Если бинарная операция не является ассоциативной, то в случае partial_sum результат будет "предсказуемый", а для inclusive_scan - нет, так как оно может суммировать (точнее, применять бинарную операцию) в "произвольном порядке"

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inclusive_scan

> In other words, the summation operations may be performed in arbitrary order, and the behavior is nondeterministic if binary_op is not associative.

ассоциативность - это следующее свойство (a+b)+c == a+(b+c)